# Haskell: `==' is not a (visible) method of class

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, instance, equality, typeclass

So, when I compile the following piece of code *edited*:

```
instance (Eq a) => PartOrd a where 
        [] == []         = True
        (x:xs) == (y:ys) = x==y && xs==ys
        _ == _           = False
        xs /= ys         = not (xs == ys)
```

I get:

```
  `==' is not a (visible) method of class 'PartOrd'

  `/=' is not a (visible) method of class 'PartOrd'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I have looked at [How to properly instantiate classes in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299951/how-to-properly-instantiate-classes-in-haskell) for some clarifications but even though I wasn`t able to fix it.

Also, is it the same when I use custom-made operators such as `=~` for `==` and `/~` for `/=`, because I get the same error?

**EDIT:** As requested:

```
class Eq a => PartOrd a where

   partcmp :: a -> a -> Maybe Ordering 
   partcmp x y = case bigger x y of
                   True   -> Just LT
                   False  -> case smaller x y of
                               True  -> Just GT
                               False -> case x == y of
                                          True  -> Just EQ
                                          False -> Nothing
```

Comment: Where is the `PartOrd` class from and what's its definition?

Comment: `EQ` and `False` are of different types: a function can not return both.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define a new `Eq` instance for the PartOrd a type, in which case you probably want something like `instance Eq a => Eq (PartOrd a)` or similar.

Comment: @user4325010 Show us your definition of `PartOrd`.

Comment: Why did you ask this question instead of commenting on my answer to your previous one? It seems you did not understand it.

Comment: Now show us your definitions of `bigger` and `smaller`. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Here are some thoughts:

1. When you declare an instance of a class like `instance (Eq a) => PartOrd a`, you are expected to provide implementations for the functions in `PartOrd a` (ie `partcmp`, not `==` and `/=`). The compiler is telling you exactly that: `==` and `/=` are in the class `Eq`, not `PartOrd`, and you have no business defining functions not in `PartOrd`. In fact, no matter whether you use `==`, or `=~` or `/~`, the problem persists: *you shouldn't be defining anything other that `partcmp` in `instance (Eq a) => PartOrd a`*. The `(Eq a) =>` part just says that in these definitions you can assume functions `==` and `/=` of type signatures `(==), (/=) :: a -> a -> a` have been defined.
2. Why are you using lists in the instance declaration? Did you maybe mean to say `instance (Eq a) => PartOrd [a]`? If you *really* meant to say `instance (Eq a) => PartOrd a`, you will need to turn on the `FlexibleInstances` (and maybe something more too...) in GHC. (However, it doesn't really make sense to have `instance (Eq a) => PartOrd a`.)
3. Finally, where do the function `bigger` and `smaller` come from? You can't use them in `class (Eq a) => PartOrd a`, since `a` is a general type. You would need functions `bigger, smaller :: a -> a -> a`, in which case you wouldn't even really need the `PartOrd` class.